# WPF AttachedProperty

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I have created a simple test project which creates a ListBox populated with Checkboxes. I have some codebehind that whenever the checkboxes are checked the TextBox above the ListBox displays the text of all the selected items. Everything works but I am now trying to create an Attached Property (again in the code behind) that allows a prefix to be included. Eventually I am looking to convert this to MVVM standards but because I am relatively new to WPF and very new to MVVM I like to work from a working sample project and gradually convert each part to an MVVM project as I find this helps me understand better what is going on.
My code is below:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckBoxList.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckBoxList"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <CheckBox
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
                                    <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="8">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ListBoxTextBox"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"  Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}" Name="lstProducts" local:MainWindow.PrefixMark=">"
         DisplayMemberPath="ModelName">
    </ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="cmdGetSelectedItems">Get Selected Items</Button>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Content="Test" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs

```
    public static string GetPrefixMark(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            string t = (string)obj.GetValue(PrefixMarkProperty);
            return (string)obj.GetValue(PrefixMarkProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPrefixMark(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(PrefixMarkProperty, value);
            string t = (string)obj.GetValue(PrefixMarkProperty);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PrefixMark.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PrefixMarkProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SetPrefixMark", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("('"));

private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is FrameworkElement element)
            {
                AddText(element);
            }
        }
private void AddText(FrameworkElement e)
        {
            StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (Product product in lstProducts.SelectedItems)
            {
                sB.Append(product.ModelName).Append(ValueSeparator);
            }
            if (sB.Length > 0)
            {
                sB.Remove(sB.Length - (ValueSeparator).Length, (ValueSeparator).Length);
            }
            if (sB.Length > 0)
            {   
                ListBoxTextBox.Text = GetPrefixMark(e) + sB.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ListBoxTextBox.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

When I run the programme although the PrefixMark is set on Load when ever I check a checkbox it reverts back to the default. I can only presume this is being created twice but for the life of me I cannot figure out why and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: `RegisterAttached("SetPrefixMark", ...)` should be `RegisterAttached("PrefixMark", ...)`. Besides that, what is the purpose of `string t` in the get and set methods of the property?

Comment: @Clemens. Thank you for the prompt response. The string t is a left over from me attempting to identify the problem. Regrettably the solution you have suggested is not working.  The SetPrefixMark is no longer being fired on startup and when checking a checkbox the PrefixMark is still returning the default?

Comment: That wasn't meant as a "solution", more a prerequisite. When you write `local:MainWindow.PrefixMark=...` in XAML, the property *must* be registered with the name `PrefixMark`, nothing else. However, I'm failing to spot a place in your code where the property is actually used.

Comment: I don't see why prefix has to be declared in xaml. it is used in c# code, declare a string constant for prefix

Comment: or you can bind TextBox.Text and include that prefix in Binding StringFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the actual name of the dependency property to the `Register` method to begin with:

```
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PrefixMark", ...
```

> The SetPrefixMark is no longer being fired on startup

It's not supposed to. If you want to set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` at startup, you should either bind it to a source property or set it programmatically:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListBoxTextBox.Text = GetPrefixMark(this);
    ...
}
```